# How to hide table footer in table component using something alike "PrintWhenExpression"?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio and I have a Jasper report made in it with a table that has several footers (dataset groups) in it. These footers contain different sums calculated across detail/groups.

Some footers need to be displayed depending on reports input parameter (`$P{myRepMode} == 1`).

Ideally I would want group footer to have a `PrintWhenExpression` field, but unluckily, Jasper Reports does not provide one. Styles (conditional) seem to not allow to set elements height either. Hiding Text in cells leaves the row empty yet still taking space.

How do I hide table footer on condition?

P.S. I know I could move sums calculations into query dataset to return everything at once and format cells based on some hints, but this would pollute data with non-data columns/rows and also require additional work.

Comment: @AlexK I'm using Jaspersoft Studio and would prefer Studio solution over manual XML editing (if possible), hence the tag.

Comment: Jaspersoft Studio is just an IDE, the solution does not depend on IDE

Comment: @AlexK Solution in this IDE will be much more favorable. Especially if further editing in this IDE wont conflict with it or break it.

Comment: I see the simple solution: to use *textField* (*staticText*) elements under the *jr:table* component with `positionType="Float"`. Yes, in this case you need to set witdh manually, depends on *table's* settings. Are you using several columns at table footer?

Comment: @AlexK Setting width manually is okay (after all it's changed rarely). The table in question has 8 columns.

Comment: This will the easiest way to solve your task. I believe, that there are no options to hide table footer (without changing JR source code)

Answer (score 1):

AFIK You can not add a `printWhenExpression` on a `jr:tableFooter` the only solution that comes close to what you are trying to achieve is to leverage textFields ability to overflow. (Not considering solutions that post elaborate the JasperReport or the JasperPrint in java)

The method would be to set the height of the `jr:tableFooter` to 1, use a `textField` with height 1, your `printWhenExpression` and select "stretch with overflow"

**Example**

```
<jr:tableFooter height="1" rowSpan="1">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
        <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9d1ad772-024d-4642-84b2-68654bf3752c">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[MyExpression]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["MyText"]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</jr:tableFooter>
```

This would come close to your desired design, if no textField the height will be only 1, if text it will show all text.

However, personally I do not like it since the field will not be visibile in IDE design view, I would consider to use another method as `textField` with float under table, `groupFooter` or change to a **normal subreport** instead of jr:table.

Comment: This works but it doenst make sense that you have to do this for it to hide.